# Computer reservation management system

Tags: linux, open-source, time-management, resource-management

Are there systems to set reservations on computer systems, in order to be able to grant access to users only on those times, and force them to log off at the end of their slot?

Basically I need an interface to reserve Linux testing machines for some time, hand out single-time logins, and kick out the user and disable that login after the time slot expires.
Bonus points if it can run scripts at beginning and end of slot.

Something like internet cafes, laboratories and libraries should use such a tool.
Ideally opensource would be the best, but if not something commercial would be good too.